# Android detect which ringtone is actually playing (Ringtone.isPlaying problem)

Tags: android, ringtone

On Android, I'm having a problem trying to figure out which ringtone is actually playing (I'm not trying to detect the default ringtone, but the one actually playing as it may be different due to user setting a particular ringtone for a particular contact).

I'm using the Ringtone.isPlaying() function as I cycle through (successfully) all the available Ringtones from the RingtoneManager. However none of them ever returns true to Ringtone.isPlaying()! Anyone have a clue what I am doing wrong? Here is the code sample that is definitely being run whilst the ring is playing:

```
RingtoneManager rm = new RingtoneManager(this); // 'this' is my activity (actually a Service in my case)
if (rm != null)
{
    Cursor cursor = rm.getCursor();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
     for (int i = 0; ; i++)
     {
            Ringtone ringtone = rm.getRingtone(i);  // get the ring tone at this position in the Cursor
            if (ringtone == null)
            break;
        else if (ringtone.isPlaying() == true)
                return (ringtone.getTitle(this));   // *should* return title of the playing ringtone
    }
    return "FAILED AGAIN!"; // always ends up here
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [source of `Ringtone`](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=media/java/android/media/Ringtone.java;h=171332431119d55aeed2e118a0640eb6b191732d;hb=HEAD) you can see that the `isPlaying()` method only cares about that particular instance of `Ringtone`.

When you call `getRingtone()` from `RingtoneManager()` it creates a new `Ringtone` object ([source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=media/java/android/media/RingtoneManager.java;h=8481410cc8f3ca69f32154a14cbd66bd1d5cd1dd;hb=HEAD)).  So this will not be the same `Ringtone` object used to play a sound when someone calls (if `Ringtone` objects are used to do that) so `isPlaying()` will always return `false` in your case.

`isPlaying()` will only ever return `true` if you have called `play()` on that specific `Ringtone` object.

As each application creates its own `MediaPlayer` objects I don't think you can monitor which sounds other applications are currently playing.

Comment: Thanks Dave,
That makes perfect sense now.
Darn, that's a shame. I'm trying to figure out which ringtone is actually playing when the phone rings. Guess I'll poke around and see if I can get a handle to the MediaPlayer object or if I can deduce which ringtone is playing by querying the contacts database vs. the incoming number or something.
Cheers,
Clive

Comment: Did you by any chance find a way to detect which ringtone is playing at the moment?