# Finding already playing ringtone

Tags: java, android

How can I find whether ringtone is already playing? If it is already playing then do not play it again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271777/how-to-set-ringtone-in-android-from-my-activity

Comment: It doesnt show how to find whether ringtone is playing currently or not.

Comment: maybe this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092470/android-detect-which-ringtone-is-actually-playing-ringtone-isplaying-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Uri ringtoneUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, ringtoneUri);
```

And check whether **ringtone** is **null** or not and make decision accordingly.