# How to get URI current/default ringtone for incoming SMS?

Tags: android, notifications, sms, ringtone

I am writing application which intented to replace standard/stock messenger. So I need to define default ringtone for incoming messages. I mean incoming SMS notification ringtone.

Anyone knows how to get it?

Comment: these link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387556/incoming-call-dynamically-override-default-ringtone          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092470/android-detect-which-ringtone-is-actually-playing-ringtone-isplaying-problem?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For default notification sound :

```
String defaultPath = Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI.getPath();
```

Answer (score 11):

To retrieve the [`Ringtone`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Ringtone.html) object of the default ringtone, use the [`RingtoneManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html):

```
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
```

If the user has changed the default ringtone to a ringtone provided in a 3rd party messager app, AFAIK you can't access the new ringtone unless the 3rd party app exposes its ringtones via a `ContentProvider`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `Notification.Builder` or `NotificationCompact.Builder` classes, calling `setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)` on the builder should do the trick.

That will play the default Notification tone that the user has picked when the system displays your notification.

Answer (score 1):

The one that helped me is 
`RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)`.